# What the best mode to implement login using Flask-Restful and SqlAlchemy (with MySql)?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

Please,

What the best mode to implement login using Flask-Restful and SqlAlchemy (with MySql)?

I'm using it and I need create a login page (using HTML + JS). What the best mode of capture the login information and send to my REST using Flask? And what the best mode to crypto password and save (and read) in the database?

I made it in other tecnnologies but not in Flask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realize that if the password implementation is not secure the users are put at risk.

Send the password to the server with HTTPS and preferwbly in a POST, not in the query string where it may be logged by the server.

On the server save the password as a password verifier. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But I need know as make in Flask. That you tell me is theory and I need about as implementation.

Comment: Your help was very important. I found lib for Bcrypt and is a good start point. https://flask-bcrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this blog [restful-authentication-with-flask by miguelgrinberg](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask/page/2)